# IIS7 or ServerManager StdOut

Tags: c#, iis-7.5, stdout, logging

Could I redirect default System.Console StdOut to IIS7 or ServerManager?

Something like:

```
System.Console.SetOut(someIIS7orServerManagerStdOut);
```

I want to read my System.Console.Write logs via IIS7/ServerManager.

Comment: FYI, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: As addition: System.Console I'll use within my IIS7 RequestHandler (via Handler Mappings);

Comment: Use trace.write line instead and register a tracer in web.config http://stackoverflow.com/q/3113650/426894

Comment: You can redirect your console writes to the trace liseners, something like shown here http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/273066-redirect-output-debug-writeline